# Best practice - component or service?

Tags: angularjs

I need to display a popup window that will be reusable throughout my AngularJS application.

Basically, I need this popup window to be called on button click in various views.

I'm using the Bootstrap UI modal popup `service` function to animate and display my popup window box. This has a defined template URL for within the popup.

```
// open popup window with uibModal 
var modal = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: "app/components/popup-template.html",
    backdrop: 'static',
    size:'lg',
    resolve: {
        someData: function () {
            return self.something;
        };
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if I should use a `component` or `service` for creating/using this popup window throughout my application. The popup needs to have a separate controller logic.

---

Question: What would be the best implementation for using this popup throughout my application, a component or service?

Comment: Components are re-usable HTML Elements, they are basically the new way to do Directives that are compatible with Angular 2.  Services are Singletons for providing reusable Injectable JavaScript objects in (usually Controller) code.

Comment: Agree with @Claies. Since your popup needs a separate controller logic, component would be the best choice. Also you can communicate with other controller if you need any bindings. It is reusable too and compatible for AngularJS 2